# Error adding new curve to survival curve in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I want to add a new line and confidence band to a survival analysis plot (Kaplan-Meier curve) created using `autoplot` from the `ggfortify` package.

However, I receive an error when using `geom_ribbon` but not when using `geom_line`. The minimal example below illustrates the issue.

```
# Load packages and data
library(survival)
library(ggfortify)
data(aml, package = "survival")

# Fit the Kaplan-Meier curve
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data=aml)

# Create an additional dataset to plot on top of the Kaplan-Meier curve
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 150, length.out=10),
                 y = seq(0, 1, length.out=10),
                 ymin = seq(0, 1, length.out=10) - 0.1,
                 ymax = seq(0, 1, length.out=10) + 0.1)
```

##### This works

```
autoplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, censor = FALSE) +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, y=ymin)) +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, y=ymax))
```

[image]

##### This does not work

```
autoplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, censor = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax))
```

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'surv' not found
```

Comment: Is there a typo in "Surv", i.e. instead of `survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data=aml)` you have `survfit(surv(time, status) ~ x, data=aml)`?

Comment: No, the code I ran is exactly the code I pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_ribbon()` you avoid that specific error, i.e.

```r
library(survival)
#install.packages("ggfortify")
library(ggfortify)
#> Warning: package 'ggfortify' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
data(aml, package = "survival")
#> Warning in data(aml, package = "survival"): data set 'aml' not found

# Fit the Kaplan-Meier curve
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data=aml)

# Create an additional dataset to plot on top of the Kaplan-Meier curve
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 150, length.out=10),
                 y = seq(0, 1, length.out=10),
                 ymin = seq(0, 1, length.out=10) - 0.1,
                 ymax = seq(0, 1, length.out=10) + 0.1)

autoplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, censor = FALSE) +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, y=ymin)) +
  geom_line(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, y=ymax))
```

[image]

```r
autoplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, censor = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, mapping = aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax),
              inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does that solve your problem?